# Hive query error : java.io.ioexception error=13 permission denied

Tags: hadoop, configuration, hive

I have a table *report* which has the fields *id,country,service,amount,count*. When I try to execute the following query in hive :

```
select * from report
```

I get the proper data from hive. But when I specify the column name in the select statement :

```
select service from report
```

I get the following exception :

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/biadmin/hadoop/bin/hadoop" (in directory "/root"): error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:617)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask.execute(MapRedTask.java:262)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1503)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1270)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1088)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:911)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:901)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:268)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:220)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:792)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:686)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:625)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:135)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1022)
    ... 21 more
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
```

I get this error in tandem, means sometimes I get it and sometimes it works fine. I tried adding the following in hive-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml, but still getting the same issue.

**hive-site.xml**

```
<property>
        <name>hive.cli.print.current.db</name>
        <value>true</value>
</property>
```

**hdfs-site.xml**

```
<property>
        <name>dfs.permissions</name>
        <value>false</value>
</property>
```

Is there any way I can avert this problem on a permanent basis. Thanks all.

Comment: Error says no permission on "/home/biadmin/hadoop/bin/hadoop"

Comment: Sorry for incomplete comment :

Comment: what is the User and Groups for /home/biadmin/hadoop/bin/hadoop. Is your user in which you are running hive part of the hadoop group which has access to hadoop bin. what are the access on your tables and data files?

Comment: Yea... The hadoop and hive has been installed within the same user and group. To be safe, I have chmod it to 777. Still I get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was simple... Assuming my hadoop installation was in ***hduser***

I used the command :

```
su hduser
```

This doesn't set all the parameters and opens in /root home folder. Hence, there are permission discrepancy.

Hence, use the command :

```
su - hduser
```

This sets the required parameters and opens directly in *hduser's* home. This doesn't give the error.

Regarding the error at tandem, I used to directly enter the server using *hduser* user which didn't give the error. But entering the server through root and then switching user gave error.